# Reference to object from grand child?

Tags: javascript

Let say a I have an object:

```js
var person= {
      firstName:"Renzo",
      getFirstName:function(){
        console.log(this);// is the person object
        return this.firstName;
      },
      address:{
        number:function(){
          console.log(this);// is the number function
          //return person.getFirstName(); // it is working
          return this.firstName;// not working           
        }
      }       
   };
   
console.log(person.getFirstName());   
console.log(person.address.number());
```

I know that "this" in the getFirstName method will reference to the person object, but "this" in the number method will not reference to the person object will reference to the number function.., I can access the getFirstName method from number function referencing to the person object, that will solve the problem but...

**Question:**
Is there way to reference the person object from the number method? without using the person variable... is there some special keyword like "this", to access the person method??

Comment: No, there is not. There's no persistent relationship between those objects in an "upward" direction. You could create a function to construct an "address" object such that it has a "person" reference.

Comment: @JozefDúc that will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 classes and arrow functions to be able to achieve this.

```
class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.firstName = "Renzo";
        this.address = {
            getNumber: () => this.firstName
        }
  }

  getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
  }
}

var person = new Person();
console.log(person.address.getNumber());
```

Here is a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/qtg1s2f2/1/

If you are looking for a reserved keyword for accessing the grand parent, there is no such thing. You will need to tweak your code to be able to do it.

Comment: thanks.. there are tons of ways but yes there is no such relationship between object and grandchild..

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could do this is during the call itself:

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'Renzo',
  getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
  },
  address: {
    number: function() {
      return this.firstName;
    }
  }
}

// then call it
person.address.number.call(person); // 'Renzo'
```

Comment: Yes that will definitely set this = person, and will work.... so I guess there is no special keyword for the person object..

Answer (score 1):

You could construct the address, so that it has access to its parent object:

```
function Person(n){
 this.firstName=n;
 this.address=new Adress(this);
}
Person.prototype= {
  firstName:"Renzo",
  getFirstName:function(){
    console.log(this);// is the person object
    return this.firstName;
  }
};

function Address(p){
 this.parent=p;
}
Address.prototype={
   number:function(){
      console.log(this);// is the number
      console.log(this.parent);//the parent
      return this.parent.getFirstName(); // it is working      
    }
 };
```

Usecase:

```
console.log((new Person("Me")).address.number());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
      var person= {
      firstName:"Renzo",
      getFirstName:function(){
        return this.firstName;
      },
      address:{
        number:function(){
          return person.firstName;
        }
      }       
   };


console.log(person.address.number());
```

Comment: Yes I know, that will solve my problem but the question was....Is there way to reference the person object from the number method? without using the person variable... is there some special keyword like "this", to access the person method??

Comment: You can return " return person.firstName; " directly from your number function;


var person= {
      firstName:"Renzo",
      getFirstName:function(){
        return this.firstName;
      },
      address:{
        number:function(){
          return person.firstName;
        }
      }       
   };

Comment: Yes that's what I did and solve the problem.. but is there some special variable??? like "this" so I don't have to use the person variable..